# Spring STOMP Broker Relay + RabbitMQ Cluster with HA Proxy fronting each for load balancing

Tags: rabbitmq, scalability, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am designing a system where a huge number of real-time data generated from devices is to be transferred to subscribers preferably over websockets. I have decided to use Spring STOMP Websockets as it was quicker to set-up, understand and had a few things supported out of the box like RabbitMQ and Security. And also because the plan is to use Spring for another REST API so Spring as a choice of tech stack. RabbitMQ is the message broker that I have decided on. However I can not find good amount of guidance on how to scale such a system.

The possible solution I am thinking of is:

- To add HAProxy in front of STOMP broker instances and also between
  STOMP Brokers and a RabbitMQ cluster, HAProxy will act as a
  load-balancer in both cases. Spring STOMP broker will then be pointing to the HAProxy as broker relay host. The requirement is to have high availability and no data loss.

As I do not have prior experience with Websockets, I would like to get guidance on if this solution sounds correct or if there is anything that I am missing here?

Note: In this system, both the message producers and consumers are actually websocket Java clients. I took the sample code from https://github.com/nickebbutt/stomp-websockets-java-client and created two separate clients - One that only sends the messages i.e. device data(Producers) and other that subscribes to these messages(Consumer). Thus both connect using same websocket URL to same STOMP broker. With above system implementation the clients will point to HAProxy for websocket connection.

Answer (score 2):

Just an updated on this, I did experimentation by creating the above set-up and it worked i.e. I was able to connect to websocket stomp server/send/receive data with RabbitMQ broker and use of HAProxy load balancing as described. The broker host/port configured in Spring was pointing to HAProxy which in turn was forwarding requests to RabbitMQ backend. Similarly, the websocket clients were connecting to Spring STOMP websocket server application via HAProxy.